# Rails 3 namespaced model and controller routing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have namespaced model `Equipment::Feature` and namespaced controller in my admin part `Admin::Equipment::FeaturesController`. Model is generic and is used as from within `:admin`  namespace and for public website. I've set up the routing for `:admin` and `:equipment` namespaces

```
namespace :admin do
  namespace :equipment do
    resources :features
  end
end
```

Which gives me following routes:

```
 admin_equipment_features     GET /admin/equipment/features(.:format)          admin/equipment/features#index
                              POST /admin/equipment/features(.:format)         admin/equipment/features#create
 new_admin_equipment_feature  GET /admin/equipment/features/new(.:format)      admin/equipment/features#new
 edit_admin_equipment_feature GET /admin/equipment/features/:id/edit(.:format) admin/equipment/features#edit
 admin_equipment_feature      GET /admin/equipment/features/:id(.:format)      admin/equipment/features#show
                              PUT /admin/equipment/features/:id(.:format)      admin/equipment/features#update
                              DELETE /admin/equipment/features/:id(.:format)   admin/equipment/features#destroy
```

Pretty standard stuff. But when I address `/admin/equipment/features` it throws `uninitialized constant Admin::Equipment::FeaturesController::Equipment` exception

`#index` action in my `Admin::Equipment::FeaturesController` looks like

```
def index
  @features = Equipment::Feature.all
end
```

It did seem to work, until I declared `Admin::Equipment` namespace. Before it was like `Admin::EquipmentFeaturesController`

I guess this is some sort of namespace collision, but I don't get it - where does it come from?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE** `Feature` model (uses STI pattern)

```
class Equipment::Feature < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :category_id, :name_en, :name_ru, :type

  belongs_to :category, :class_name => 'Equipment::Category'

  has_many :item_features, :class_name => 'Equipment::ItemFeature'
  has_many :items, :through => :item_features

  translates :name
end

class FeatureBoolean < Equipment::Feature

end

class FeatureNumeric < Equipment::Feature

end

class FeatureString < Equipment::Feature

end

class FeatureRange < Equipment::Feature

end
```

**UPDATE2**
Fixing `#index` action as per answer below resolved the issue. New code:

```
def index
  @features = ::Equipment::Feature.all
end
```

Comment: Please show the code from your feature model.

Comment: Updated question. `Feature` model uses STI pattern and has `type` column with STI class name as per Rails convention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's now looking for `Feature` in `Admin::Equipment`, rather than in `::Equipment`

Try specifying that there is no namespace, i.e.

```
def index
  @features = ::Equipment::Feature.all
end
```

Comment: Oh thanks! It worked! I did not know that prefixing namespace with `::` kind of 'resets' namespace resolving.

Answer (score 1):

Please create folder like this app/controllers/admin/equipment/features.rb

And then edit your controller name to Admin::Equipment::FeaturesController

```
class Admin::Equipment::FeaturesController < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```